# Template.meteorError.rendered doesn't work in errors meteor package

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

I am trying to use **meteor-errors** package in [my meteor project](https://github.com/CoinsManager/CoinsManager).

It has two main files with javascript code:

**errors_list.js:**

```js
Template.meteorErrors.helpers({
    errors: function() {
       return Errors.collection.find();
    }
});

Template.meteorError.rendered = function() {
  var error = this.data;
  Meteor.defer(function() {
    Errors.collection.update(error._id, {$set: {seen: true}});
  });
};
```

**errors.js:**

```js
Errors = {
  // Local (client-only) collection
  collection: new Meteor.Collection(null),

  throw: function(message) {
    Errors.collection.insert({message: message, seen: false})
  },
  clearSeen: function() {
    Errors.collection.remove({seen: true});
  }
};
```

But looks like **Template.meteorError.rendered** method doesn't work. And I can't set status of elements from my error's collection as **seen: true**.

When I call for example:

**(server)**

```js
throw new Meteor.Error 401, "You need to login to add a new address"
```

**(client)**

```
Meteor.call "verify_address", address, name, (error, result) ->
  if error
    Errors.throw error.reason
```

I got this error message in my markup, but my browser console shows:

```js
Errors.collection.find().fetch()

[Object]
_id: "MZ8TzpsKCXaeC33Jn"
message: "Address not the correct size"
seen: false
__proto__: Object
```

And message's seen attribute is still "false".

The initial problem was that an error has a 'X' icon that does not remove the error when clicked. How are we supposed to remove the errors?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the strange behavior is, you are manually throwing a `Meteor.Error` whereas your template is bound to a collection which is populated by calling `Errors.throw(message)`

Try this:

```
Errors.throw('You need to login to add a new address');
```

Comment: I use: throw new Meteor.Error 401, "My message" on the server-side, but on the client-side I use: Errors.throw error.reason So I already use it as you suggest, but without any success

Comment: What happens when you just Errors.throw('some error message') on browser console? Meteor.Error is completely decoupled from the Errors package you are trying to use. Are you following the discovermeteor book example?

Comment: If I enter Errors.throw('some error message') on browser console, I see the new error message on the page "some error message", but also can't hide it. And yes, I follow discovermeteor book, but can't figure out where is my mistake.

Comment: Hiding messages is done by marking them as read in a Meteor.defer function. You'll see that later on in the book.